# Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\ln x \, dx$

Tags: integration, limits

I have a question about the integral of $\ln x$.

When I try to calculate the integral of $\ln x$ from 0 to 1, I always get the following result.

- $\int_0^1 \ln x = x(\ln x -1) |_0^1 = 1(\ln 1 -1) - 0 (\ln 0 -1)$

Is the second part of the calculation indeterminate or 0?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Joachim G.

Comment: How did you conclude that the second part is indeterminate?

Answer (score 22):

$\ln x$ is not defined at $0$ so the integral
$$\int_0^1\ln x\, dx$$
is improper. Thus,
\begin{align} \int_0^1\ln x\, dx &= (x\ln x -x)|_0^1 \\ &=1\ln 1-1-\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x-0 \\ &= -1+\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x. \end{align}
We need to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln x}{\frac1x}.$$
Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
Yes i can do that :)

Comment: @nameless The integral is perfectly defined as a Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 21):

Looking sideways at the graph of $\log(x)$ you can also see that $$\int_0^1\log(x)dx = -\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx = -1.$$

Comment: +1 though I see $$- \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^x \, dx =-1$$

Comment: @Henry Did you use a mirror?  ;-)  But sure, that works too.

Comment: quick question why is it negative?